# Roslyn: how to move caret after applying a code fix

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm using Roslyn inside my own IDE which uses a custom project system (not the VS one). I'm currently using `AdHocWorkspace` as the Roslyn workspace.

I'm supporting code fixes in my IDE via the CodeFixProviders contained in the Roslyn assemblies. The fixes apply operations on my workspace just fine, but I'm wondering if it's possible to get the new caret position after applying a fix?

For example, if a user types `HttpClient` in my editor and then uses a code fix to add the `System.Net.Http` namespace, the position of the `HttpClient` token changes (because of the extra text at the beginning of the file), but I'd like to keep the caret where it was relative to that token.

[image]

For this particular case, I use a `ProjectSymbolReferenceCodeAction` action, and the only operation this action returns from `GetOperationsAsync` is an `ApplyChangesOperation` operation. I was expecting that perhaps it might also return another operation for moving the caret but it didn't.

I'm assuming it might have to do with the fact that `AdHocWorkspace` does not imply an IDE and hence does not support the concept of caret position, but I don't know if that's the case, and if so, how to go about creating my own workspace that would support this.

**TLDR:** can you point me in the right direction on how to handle moving the caret after applying a code fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in Visual Studio, this works because when we ultimately apply the edit back to the text buffer, we're computing a text diff against the original file. We only apply that difference, and the editor component automatically tracks where the cursor position is around that edit. It automatically computes "oh, the caret was at position 100, but you added 20 characters at the start, so now you're at position 120." I'm not sure which editor component you're using or how you're applying the contents back, but you'll want to see if it supports diffing for you so the cursor isn't jumping around, or you'll want to recompute the new location based on the diff that you applied.

Comment: Ah, so that's how it's done. I was thinking since the code code action is the thing that specifies the change that it should also suggest the new caret position. Using a single diff based mechanism absolves the code actions of this burden, though, so that makes sense. I use AvalonEdit as the editor. I also replace the entire document on each change (OT: does this slow things down, should I be using a different approach?).

Comment: I can't speak to AvalonEdit's API, but I can't imagine replacing the entire document is going to be great if you have a very large file scenario to deal with. It's not uncommon for us to see files that are multiple megabytes in size. But without knowing your users it's hard to say.

Comment: And as I was refactoring some other code I coincidentally ran into https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/d0d9a59a9c222e58e679645ff5fdc2c074c8335e/src/EditorFeatures/Core.Wpf/Suggestions/SuggestedActions/SuggestedAction.CaretPositionRestorer.cs where we have some subtle tricks atop the standard editor behavior for us. But general lesson is that's being done at the core code action layer, and it's using the editor's diffing behavior to help us.

Comment: Got it, so calculating the diff is the key, both for updating the documents (with SourceText.WithChanges) as well as for moving the caret.